# Show $n!=\omega(2^n)$ using Stirling's Approximation

Tags: asymptotics, limits-without-lhopital

I'm faced with a question to show that $n!=\omega(2^n)$ using Stirling's Approximation $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}n^{n}$.

Showing $n!=\omega(2^n)$ is equivalent to showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{n!}{2^n}}=\infty$.

I tried:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}n^{n}}}&=1\\
{\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{n!}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}n^{n}}}}&=1\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n!}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}n^{n}}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{n!}{2^n}}&=?\\
 {\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg[\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{-n}n^{n}\bigg]}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{2^n}}}&=?\\
 {\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg[\sqrt{2\pi n}\bigg]\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg[e^{-n}\bigg]}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg[n^{n}\bigg]}}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{2^n}}}&=?\\
\end{align*}$$

At this point I feel I'm wrong and can't continue since $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg[e^{-n}\bigg]}=0$, so I can't get the result I want. Any ideas?

Comment: You should just put Stirling's approximation divided by $2^n$ as the limit term.  Then you can note that $e^{-n}=\frac 1{e^n}$ and combine terms...

Comment: You don't even need something as powerful as Stirling's approximation to show that $\frac{n!}{2^n} \to \infty$. Just notice that $n! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n \geq 3^{n-2}$. And thus $\frac{n!}{ 2^n} \geq \frac{1}{9} \cdot (3/2)^n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Shalop, or $n! \geq 4^{n-3}=2^{2n-6}$ would give $n!/2^n > 2^{n-6}$ which might be slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Stiling's Formula is

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\frac{n!}{2^n}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)}{2^n}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

Now, for $n\ge 6$, $\frac{n}{2e}>1$.  Therefore, $\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, from which it is easy to see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $a_k$ is a non-decreasing positive sequence, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+a_n)^n=\infty$$